# How to trigger a method from a custom control which inherits from another custom control?

Tags: delphi

**Overview**

To put the question into text more simply, the inheritance of my control looks like this:

`TCustomListBox` > `TMyCustomListBox` > `TMyListBox`

The reason for `TMyCustomListBox` is to expand on `TCustomListBox` by adding some of my own new properties and methods, and then I will have other `TMyListBox` components that will derive from `TMyCustomListBox`, but may also have their own properties and methods.

**Problem**

The problem I am facing is not been able to fire the method from `TMyListBox` which I introduced in `TCustomListBox`.

With that in mind, here is a broken down snippet for `TMyCustomListBox` where you can see the new method type I have added (*OnAddition*):

```
type
  TOnAdditionEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; Index: Integer; Value: string) of object;

  TMyCustomListBox = class(TCustomListBox)
  private
    FOnAddition: TOnAdditionEvent;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property OnAddition: TOnAdditionEvent read FOnAddition write FOnAddition;
    property OnClick;
    property OnDblClick;
    // ...
  end;
```

I assign the event like so:

```
if Assigned(FOnAddition) then
begin
  FOnAddition(Self, SomeIndex, SomeValue);
end;
```

The above is called from:

```
procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
```

---

Now we have `TMyListBox`:

```
type
  TMyListBox = class(TMyCustomListBox)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;
```

If I were to use an instance of `TMyListBox` at designtime and use the new event, it works without fault when tested at runtime:

```
procedure Form1.MyListBox1Addition(Sender: TObject; Index: Integer; Value: string);
begin
  ShowMessage('Added Item: [' + Value + '] whose index is: ' + IntToStr(Index));
end;
```

How do I do the same within the `TMyListBox` components source, I tried a few different things and either nothing fires the event or I get errors.

---

**What I tried**

***1***

```
type
  TMyListBox = class(TMyCustomListBox)
  protected
    procedure Addition(Sender: TObject; Index: Integer; Value: string);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TMyListBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  OnAddition := Addition; // shouldn't this call Addition procedure below?
end;

procedure TMyListBox.Addition(Sender: TObject; Index: Integer;
  Value: string);
begin
  ShowMessage('test'); // doesnt fire
end;
```

***2***

Same as above, only adding `inherited`:

```
procedure TMyListBox.Addition(Sender: TObject; Index: Integer;
  Value: string);
begin
  inherited; // no difference
  ShowMessage('test'); // doesnt fire
end;
```

***3***

I tried overriding the `Addition` method declaration:

```
procedure Addition(Sender: TObject; Index: Integer; Value: string); override;
```

Errors with `Addition` not found in base class.

***4***

I even tried changing the declaration to:

```
procedure OnAddition(Sender: TObject; Index: Integer; Value: string);
```

and removing the event handler from the constructor, still doesnt fire.

I tried a few other things too but at this point I have ran into a dead end so would appreciate a nudge in the right direction. I really should be able to solve this but I think I have been spending too long stuck at this one problem and my brain is melting, so I await what will most likely turn out to be a simple obvious answer :)

Thanks.

Comment: We cannot answer, because you don't show how you fire the event from within TMyCustomListBox.

Comment: On another note, custom components (`TMyCustomListBox`) typically shouldn't have anything published yet. You also shouldn't be using this component for anything other than inheriting from, and those inherited ones should publish the properties it needs. `TMyCustomListBox` should only be the base for all other inherited controls, and not used by itself.

Comment: Do you have you event hooked up in the IDE? There is a chance that the streaming is overriding your event hookup. Also, try and put `OnAddition := Addition;` in an AfterContruction and see what happens.

Comment: @NGLN I edited the question to show how the event is assigned in `TMyCustomListBox`. As I Remy understands I can call the event without problem, it was just trying to get it to fire from `TMyListBox` that is not triggering.

Comment: @Blobby: You have not shown where and under what conditions `OnAddition` is being fired. You only said it was being fired inside of `WndProc()`. In any case, once you apply my solution, change `WndProc()` to call `DoAssigned(SomeIndex, SomeValue);` instead of `if Assigned(FOnAddition) then begin FOnAddition(Self, SomeIndex, SomeValue); end;`

Comment: @JerryDodge you and Remy are right, what I thought I wanted to achieve and what I actually achieved proved to be wrong, so I better think again what I need to do.

Comment: @Graymatter what do you mean `AfterConstruction`? in the `Loaded` procedure or something?

Comment: @Blobby AfterConstuction is a method on TObject that you can override. So you would override the method add an inherited as the first line and then do whatever you need to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> constructor TMyListBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
> begin
>   inherited Create(AOwner);
>   OnAddition := Addition; // shouldn't this call Addition procedure below?
> end;
> ```

This assignment should work just fine.  And no, it does not *call* `Addition()`, it *assigns the address* of `Addition()` to the `OnAddition` event.  When the event is triggered, it will then *call* `Addition()`.

However, that being said, this is the wrong design.  A component should *NEVER* assign a handler to its own events (especially `published` events).  The correct solution is to have `TMyCustomListBox` declare a `virtual` method that triggers `OnAddition` and then call that method when needed.  `TMyListBox` (or any other descendant) can then `override` that method, calling `inherited` if/when it wants to trigger the user's `OnAddition` event handler.  The added benefit is that this also allows descendants to react to the event even if the user does not assign any event handler.

Try this instead:

```
type
  TOnAdditionEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; Index: Integer; Value: string) of object;

  TMyCustomListBox = class(TCustomListBox)
  private
    FOnAddition: TOnAdditionEvent;
  protected
    procedure DoAddition(Index: Integer; Value: string); virtual;
    property OnAddition: TOnAdditionEvent read FOnAddition write FOnAddition;
  // ...
  end;

procedure TMyCustomListBox.DoAddition(Index: Integer; Value: string);
begin
  if Assigned(OnAddition) then
   OnAddition(Self, Index, Value);
end;
```

```
type
  TMyListBox = class(TMyCustomListBox)
  protected
    procedure DoAddition(Index: Integer; Value: string); override;
  // ...
  published
    property OnAddition;
  //...
  end;

procedure TMyListBox.DoAddition(Index: Integer; Value: string);
begin
  ShowMessage('test'); // doesnt fire
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Your example misses the part where the event is fired from the component. Somewhere must be the call of `DoAddition( ... )`

Comment: The fact that the `OnAddition` event is getting triggered at runtime means he is firing the event correctly in `TMyCustomListBox`. The question he asked is how to make `TMyListBox` react to the event, and my solution is the way to do that correctly.  But yes, `TMyCustomListBox` does need to call `DoAddition()` wherever it is currently calling `OnAddition(Self, ...)` directly.

Comment: That is correct, it fires from `TMyCustomListBox` and by using an instance of `TMyListBox`, but trying to fire directly from `TMyListBox` is the problem. Let me take some time to properly look at your answer thanks.

Comment: @Blobby: "but trying to fire directly from TMyListBox is the problem", what do you mean exactly? If you are having firing issues, then you need to show your firing code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau your answer works, mine didnt - I thought the code I posted showed the firing code. Anyway the answer is correct but as you and others have pointed out this is not an ideal way (what I thought and planned originally obviously didnt become the most suitable way). So I will accept your answer, take notes from these answers and rethink what I need to do more logically. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that in TMyCustomListbox you declare OnAdition as property of TOnAdditionEvent but in TMyListBox you try declaring this as procedure.

So the correct approach would be to declare your TMyListBox like so:

```
type
  TMyListBox = class(TMyCustomListBox)
  protected
    procedure Addition(Sender: TObject; Index: Integer; Value: string);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property OnAddition; //This forwards the parent property definition to the child
  end;

constructor TMyListBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  OnAddition := Addition; // shouldn't this call Addition procedure below?
end;

procedure TMyListBox.Addition(Sender: TObject; Index: Integer;
  Value: string);
begin
  ShowMessage('test'); // doesnt fire
end;
```

And to fire the event outside the TMyListBox class call:

```
MyListBox.OnAddition(Self, SimeIndex, SomeValue);
```

And if you are doing it from within the class you can call:

```
Self.OnAddition(Self, SimeIndex, SomeValue);
```

NOTE: If you ever want to reuse parents property in child class without any making changes use:

```
property MyParentProperyName;
```

You don't need to declare property type nor getter or setter methods unes you want to do some changes to the way how property is handled (converting full acces property from paret clas to become read only in child class for instance).